# Can't access swift files in Unit test target in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

Adding swift files to test target will work, but it is not the best way to do. My problem is I can't able to access Swift file whereas Objective-C files are accessible.

I have checked product module name and set configuration file same as project file for test target. Even removed the test target and readded, but, still encountering "Use of undeclared type in SlideViewController".

Can anyone help me with solving this issue?

Answer (score 13):

By default you won't be able to access internal classes from your unit test target.

The apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/04-writing_tests.html) on writing tests with swift say that you need to take two steps to get around this:

1. Set the `ENABLE_TESTABILITY` build setting to YES.
2. Add @testable to the import statement for your module. `@testable import MySwiftApp`

If you follow both of those steps your SlideViewController (as long as it is not a private class) should be accessible from your unit test file as if it was declared as an open class.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this on top of your test file:

`@testable import <YOUR_MODULE_NAME>`

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes you will need to add files to the build phases of your test target.

1.- Go to project navigator

2.- Select your project

3.- On the project and target list, select the target for your tests (Ex. "MyProjectTests")

4.- Select Build Phases tab

5.- Open "Compile Sources"

6.- Using the plus sign, add the files needed for the compilation

Comment: This then adds the swift file to unit test target membership, which isn't ideal.